# Travelling to Lisbon from India

Tags: india, paris, lisbon, madrid

I am planning to travel to Lisbon on 23/September and return to India on 6/October.

I am planning to travel to Paris/Madrid and then take a train from there.

Can some one tell me how much time does it take to reach Lisbon from Paris/Madrid and what is the frequency of trains.

Do I need transit visa for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Paris and Madrid are over 1,000km apart, so it's really not a situation where the two cities are interchangeable.

From Madrid, you can [reach Lisbon by sleeper train or a series of daytime connections](https://www.seat61.com/international-trains/trains-from-Madrid.htm#Spain-Portugal). The [overnight sleeper](https://www.seat61.com/trains-and-routes/trainhotel-lusitania-from-madrid-to-lisbon.htm) takes about 9.5 hours, running once per night. By daytime train, it will take pretty much the entire day; if you follow the Man in Seat 61's suggested itinerary, you'll leave at 8am and arrive at 8pm.

[From Paris](https://www.seat61.com/international-trains/trains-from-Paris.htm#Paris-Lisbon), you can take the TGV to the Spanish border, then connect to a [Sud Express](https://www.seat61.com/trains-and-routes/sud-express-from-irun-and-san-sebastian-to-lisbon.htm) sleeper train to Lisbon. You'd leave Paris at 12:52 and arrive in Lisbon about 7:30 the next morning.

Given the amount of time these journeys require, I'd give serious consideration to flying instead. There are also [bus options](https://www.busbud.com/en/bus-schedules-results/ezjmgt/eycs20?outbound_date=2018-04-25&adults=1) available, taking 8-9 hours from Madrid to Lisbon.

If you're an Indian citizen, you need a Schengen visa for your entire trip, which would cover your time in Lisbon and your time spent in France and/or Spain.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I do not know about the visa rules. Are you saying with Schengen visa I can travel from India to Madrid to Lisbon? I think I have conveyed it to you as I will be there only for 3 days 23,24 and 25... That was my mistake. I am saying I will be traveling from India in one of these days and be there till 6 th October.. I have edited the question

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Yes, exactly. Spain, Portugal, and France are all countries in the Schengen area, so one visa will work for them all.

Comment: Even if you're there longer, personally, I'd fly unless the overnight train meets your needs.